# jquery click event not working... or doing anything at all...

Tags: jquery, click, bind

Not sure why the code below isn't working... I've tried a number of variations:

```
$('button.mytestbutton').live('click', function() ... 
$('button.mytestbutton').bind('click', function() ...
$('button.mytestbutton').click(function() ...
```

etc., etc.  I've also tried inserting return false; before the closing });

In firebug, I don't get anything at all in the console.  Absolutely no indication that it's been clicked at all... Is there something about "button" that prevents me from doing this?

Here's the current jquery iteration:

```
  $('button.mytestbutton').live('click', function() {
    $('#progress').append('Ok, I clicked it.');
    return false;
  });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<button class="mytestbutton">Test</button>
<div id="progress"></div>
```

I also don't see any errors in Firebug on initial page load, and when I check the `<script></script>` tags, I see the js there... Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Works fine here buddy [http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/KkLDq/](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/KkLDq/)

Comment: My first guess is that you aren't wrapping your code with  `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code goes here*/});`.. When the javascript is executed, there are no html elements yet...

Comment: It seems to be working correctly for me in FF5 and IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Aw/ and it worked perfectly fine. Could there be other JavaScript or HTML IDs that are preventing the action from going? It even works when I use `.click` instead of `.live`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your events are attached after the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(function(){

// event binding code can go here.

});
```

This is an equivelent to `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

just use `$('button.mytestbutton').click();` (don't declare a new function within click(). that overides the first one)

#### EDIT:

unless I completely missunderstood you :P

Comment: Click event handlers are not overwritten, they are appended.

Answer (score 0):

Its is maybe an error on another part of your script... It happend to me too, without firebug error, you have to check all of your js code